# Rounding the angle of element

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to round all gameobject transform elements to 2nd decimal point. Every seems to work well, exept the case when the value of element is written exponetial notation (i.e. -1.2517e-06). The second problem is that in localRotation i have a problem because it do not change.

Here is the working localPosition (exept e notation):

```
o.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(
     (float)System.Math.Round(o.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition.x, 2),
     (float)System.Math.Round(o.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition.y, 2),
     (float)System.Math.Round(o.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition.z, 2));
```

Here is the not working localRotation:

```
o.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localRotation = new Quaternion(
     (float)System.Math.Round(o.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localRotation.x, 2), 
     (float)System.Math.Round(o.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localRotation.y, 2),
     (float)System.Math.Round(o.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localRotation.z, 2),
     (float)System.Math.Round(o.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localRotation.w, 2));
```

do you have any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: Have you tried manipulating Euler Angles instead of Quaternion components directly?

Comment: Not really but this


`o.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3((float)System.Math.Round(o.transform.localEulerAngles.x, 2), 
                    (float)System.Math.Round(o.transform.localEulerAngles.y, 2),
                    (float)System.Math.Round(o.transform.localEulerAngles.z, 2));`

 seems to be working well

Comment: euler angles are rotations around the 3 axes of the coordnate system and therefor easily "human readable". quaternions are something completely different, see them as sort of encoded rotation for ease of computation, you should not manipulate them directly.  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation